# Django: how can I reach the post data inside the serializer?

Tags: django-rest-framework

In the `Carpets` model I have no field  called `information`, but I am trying to post request with additional information field with the help of serializer, therefore I am  looking for a way to reach the `information` field in the post request in serializer and return it as `information` field. I tried `self.validated_data` but it only returns `name` and `year` field.

> made request

```
from rest_framework import request
import requests;
endpoint='http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/post/carpet/'
response=requests.post(endpoint,json={'name':'Iranian Carpet','year':1992,'information':'It is the oldest carpet of Iran'})
print(response.json());
```

> models.py

```
class Carpets(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255);
    year=models.PositiveIntegerField();
```

> serializer.py

```
class CarpetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    information=serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta():
        model=Carpets;
        fields=['name','year','information'];

    def get_information(self,obj) :
       try:
           return obj.get_information()
       except: 
         return self.validated_data.get('information')
```

> views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def post_carpet(request,*args,**kwargs):
    data={};
    serializer=CarpetSerializer(data=request.data);
    if serializer.is_valid():
     data=serializer.data
    else:
     print('serializer is not valid') 
    return JsonResponse(data);
```

Comment: `request.data`?

Comment: Where I can reach the request? inside serializer

Comment: or `self.data` in the serializer.

Comment: it gives RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by just   adding the context in views.py

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def post_carpet(request,*args,**kwargs):
    data={};
    serializer=CarpetSerializer(data=request.data,context={'request':request});
    if serializer.is_valid():
     data=serializer.data
    else:
     print('serializer is not valid') 
    return JsonResponse(data);
```

serializer.py

```
class CarpetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    information=serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta():
        model=Carpets;
        fields=['name','year','information'];

    def get_information(self,obj) :
       try:
           return obj.get_information()
       except: 
          return self.context['request'].data['information']
```